# How to filter with a month range using sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I want to search and filter using sunspot. I want to filter using month number on a date field "date_start". How can i filter using just the month part of my date field?

I tried something like this :

```
with(:date_start).greater_than(3)
```

Thank you for help

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a virtual attribute to your model, for example:

```
def month
  self.date_start.strftime('%m')
end
```

Then add it to index and search it!